# Hide 2 successive information in ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some array `MyArray`:

```
MyArray =  [{'prop1':a, 'prop2':b, 'prop3':c},
            {'prop1':a, 'prop2':d, 'prop3':e},
            {'prop1':a, 'prop2':d, 'prop3':h}];
```

I'm using `ng-repeat` to display it:

```
<tr ng-repeat="value in MyArray">
     <td>{{value.prop1}}</td>
     <td>{{value.prop2}}</td>
     <td>{{value.prop3}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I would like to hide the display of 2 successive values in my table:

```
a    |    b   |    c
     |    d   |    e
     |        |    h
```

So if the `prop1` of element 1 is the same as the `prop1` of element 2, I would like to hide the `prop1` of the second line. Same for the second `prop2`

Is it possible easily?

Comment: Good homework, please show what you did? which part of the code doesn't work for you

Comment: Sounds like a job for a filter

Comment: thank you @tbone849, I will check on that direction :)